See only black screen with "X" cursor when logging in sometimes
I am currently running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, but this has happened on previous releases too. Some notes:

I do see the UI in the log in screen, but this issue (black screen with X cursor) only happens after log in.
Once in this state, I cannot do anything except for force the power off via the hardware switch
Usually on the second boot, the system works as expected.

My graphics card:
2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M] (rev c7)

Does anyone have any insight into this issue?
